# Parsley Validation throwing: Validator `undefined` does not handle multiple values

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

I have a form in a modal I'm trying to manually POST using ajax after it has been successfully validated by Parsley. When the modal is opened, I first initialise Parsley on the form with:

```
modalLaunchers.createTaskFormValidation = $(document.getElementById('create-task-form')).parsley(parsleyOptions);
```

When the form is then submitted, I have the following code:

```
  modalLaunchers.createTaskFormValidation.validate();
  if (modalLaunchers.createTaskFormValidation.isValid()) {
         // do ajax POST
    }
```

If there are incorrect fields, these are correctly highlighted. However, if those fields are then corrected and the form resubmitted, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Validator `undefined` does not handle multiple values
```

Both validate() and isValid() throw that error.

Obviously I want the form to be re-validated when submit is pressed again and if it is valid, continue to the POST. However, because that error is thrown it doesn't proceed any further. My Parsely options are below:

```
const parsleyOptions = {
    // errorsWrapper: '',
    errorTemplate: '<span class="error-msg"></span>',
    // successClass: 'has-success',
    errorClass: 'has-error',
    classHandler: (el) => {
        console.log(el.$element.closest('div.form-group'));
        return el.$element.closest('div.form-group');   
    },
    excluded: 'input.select2-search__field',
};
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot

Comment: Without the content of `parsleyOptions`, and calls to `addValidator`, it's impossible to tell.
*Pro tip*: always post a minimal live example.

Comment: I've updated it to include the options now. There are no calls to addValidator, and everything is done via data attributes. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe an invalid validation on a multiple value input like select boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work, but using a try catch block around the validate. It's very odd because when the validate function throws the error when it is used again after the initial validation, it still updates the parsley object with whether the individual fields have failed or not (via the fields.field.validationResult property) and updates the UI with the failed fields. Thus the below works (though it does feel very messy):

```
            event.preventDefault();
            try {
                modalLaunchers.createTaskFormValidation.validate();
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            if (modalLaunchers.createTaskFormValidation.fields.some(field => field.validationResult !== true) === false) {

    // ensure every field.validationResult is true. If it is, continue to the post, if not return and keep the UI errors

            }
```

Still not sure if this is a bug or my incorrect implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain exactly why, but we had this error because we used

`= f.input :read_parent_info, as: :boolean, required: true, input_html: {data: {parsley_select_yes:''}`

but I noticed it was fine for this one:

```
= f.input :read_code_conduct, as: :radio_buttons, required: true, input_html: {data: {parsley_select_yes:''}}, collection: @enrolment_service.yes_no_radio_options,
```

the difference is that the buggy one is type :boolean whereas the one that works is a radio.

So maybe in your form you are doing something similar.